# Where's To Download PHP5-PGSQL Modules for RHEL 4

Tags: php, postgresql

I wanna ask where and how to install PHP-PGSQL modules for RHEL4.
Because I've tried "yum install php5-pgsql" not found, I've tried "php-pgsql" the message my modules is more update than it
anyone can help me

Answer (score 1):

most of these packages are not available in default yum repositories.
so you need to another repository like EPEL or Atom, which will surely provide this package.

Comment: is there any option to install them without yum?example using rpm maybe.

Comment: yes. but for that you will run into trouble, as resolution of dependencies(which is efficiently done by yum) will be needed to be resolved manually, which is a big headache. Here is URL of the rpm: ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/4/remi/i386/php-pgsql-5.3.8-5.el4.remi.i386.rpm " you can find rpm suited for your PHP version number and distro.